# Alternatives to using a linked server sql

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server

I am on hosting plan that will not allow me to create or configure a linked server in SQL Server, only realized this when I was way advanced in my work. So changing hosting companies is out of the question. My question is what other alternative methods or tricks or hacks or ways are at my disposal to be able to perform a select query from two different database on the same instance and give me joined results which I want to post to a temporary table in database (A) which is the main database I am working with. The tables from both database are identical and I am using c# asp.net 4.5.6.

---

After some more digging I discovered I had asked this question totally wrong, I had misinterpretation of my situation now I have discover the real question.

How do you construct a select query that will return a single set of results from two identical tables on two different databases on the same sql server instant.

Comment: `two different database on the same instance` - there is no need in linked **SERVER** at all.

Comment: What are you trying to do and why would you need a linked server? Why not use multiple databases or multiple schemas in the same database?

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos please ex-plane further for I am looking for any other alternatives.

Comment: @IvanStarostin so what you suggest I do ??

Comment: `mssql cross database queries`

Comment: @MarcosJ.DJunior to do what? You haven't explained *what* you want to do or what the problem is. You mentioned what you tried to do to solve it - use linked servers. You *don't* need linked servers though, when you can create multiple databases on the same server instance with a `CREATE DATABASE` statement

Comment: @IvanStarostin can you please post your suggestion as an answer with a working example code " mssql cross database queries " I think that is what I need.

Comment: google.com to the rescue.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos - "My question is what other alternative methods or tricks or hacks or ways are at my disposal to be able to perform a select query from two different database on the same instance and give me joined results which I want to post to a temporary table in database (A) which is the main database I am working with" Before I post I truly spend time googling, when I come here is because I am seeking direction. by the way I too am father of 6.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos How can I construct a select query for two identical tables from the same server instant but in two different databases. each database is password protected.....Is That clearer for??

Comment: @MarcosJ.DJunior If you want to query different databases just use a different `Initial Catalog` parameter in the connection string. Or use a three-part name to refer to the tables. Instead of `dbo.SomeTable` use `SomDb.dbo.SomeTable`

Comment: @MarcosJ.DJunior what is your *actual* problem though? Why did you try to use linked servers in the first place? Are you trying to create a multi-tenant application and thought you need linked servers for this?

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I think that is where i threw myself off, up to now I had thought I needed linked SERVERS I have discovered so far that i dont need linked servers at all. Now I think you now have the picture from what I need can you please provide me with a code snippet on how to achieve what you suggested.

Comment: Mr down voter, if I could ask my question professionally and eloquently with so much grace like you would, then I don't think i will be asking the question in the first place because I would understand what I want. As for those who understand not all of us could afford to go to dev school or varsity and took their time to understand my question. I got a working answer after some guidance under the comments section of my question, my issue was solved which is more important to me. So you welcome down voter i am here for answers not reputation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Following the comments in your first post...It has been concluded that you don't need to use linked servers since your databases belong on the same server.

When you set up a connection to SQL Server you can access all the databases on that server(assuming you have access to them). 
Initial Catalog in the connection string is used to tell what database you want the connection string to connect to initialy.

Answering your question:  "....How do you construct a select query that will return a single set of results from two identical tables on two different databases on the same sql server instant."

The definition of single set of results is not quite clear, but below are two examples of how you can work with tables in different databases (on the same server)

```
select  column1,column2,etc.. from databaseA.yourSchema.yourTable t1
left join databaseB.yourSchema.yourTable t2 on t1.YourKey = t2.YourKey
```

If you want to combine the two tables simply:

```
Select * from databaseA.yourSchema.yourTable
UNION ALL 
Select * from databaseB.yourSchema.yourTable
```

Comment: thank you for taking time to analyse my question, that is exactly what I was looking for, being a self trained developer & lack of formal training; I was not able to express my requirements properly in the first question, but that last code did it for me. Many thanks